# Llamar a mi paquete NPM (modulo de Node) sin agregar el .js

Tags: nodejs, npm

Hola estoy programando un módulo para `nodejs` que se instala a través de `npm`, todo funciona genial, el código, la instalación, todo como tiene que ser etc..., mi inquietud es que para utilizar otros módulos no es necesario agregar el *.js* al hacer el `require` por ejemplo:

```
cons paquete = require('paquete')
```

en cambio el mío, si no coloco *.js* al nombre del paquete este me dice que no lo encuentra, osea tengo que llamarlo así:

```
cons mipaquete = require('mipaquete.js')
```

¿Alguna idea de por que sucede esto y de cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al usar `const paquete = require('paquete')` nodejs buscará de manera jerárquica en:

1. `./node_modules/paquete.js`
2. `./node_modules/paquete/index.js`
3. `./node_modules/paquete/package.json`

Primero intenta ubicar el archivo como un `.js` en la carpeta `node_modules` (si la ruta es relativa), si no lo encuentra, buscará un directorio con el nombre del paquete y dentro ubicará el archivo `index.js`, si no tiene éxito buscará finalmente, en ese mismo directorio, la entrada `main` en el archivo `package.json`.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando dentro de un archivo js haces:

```
require('./algo')
```

Node va a buscar en el `directorio algo` por un archivo `index.js`, si no lo encuentra, busca por `index.json`, si no busca por `index.node` y si no encuentra nada de lo anterior, pues obviamente lanza un error.
**[DOCUMENTACIÓN](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together)**